# PDF with table of unknown width using iText XMLWorker

Tags: html, pdf-generation, itext, xmlworker

I am using XMLWorker in iText to create a PDF from an HTML table. Is it possible to create a table of unknown width (width: auto)? It seems that iText is making all tables width 100% unless a width is set explicitly.

This works as expected:

```
<table style="width: 600px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This produces a table with a width of 100%:

```
<table style="width: auto">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In PDF land (ignoring iText for a moment), everything is absolute. There's no 50%, 2/3, `calc()` or anything like that. Every page (very important to remember `page`) has defined dimensions that cannot be changed (without making another PDF). Also, there's no HTML. That's really important. So iText needs to convert loose HTML markup into 100% exact PDF syntax that is guaranteed to render exactly the same on every conformant device out there. All 100%, auto, whatever needs to be turned into exact units and that's what you are seeing.

Comment: @Dustin what do you expect instead? How could a width of something drawn be *unknown*?

Comment: I would expect it to work similarly to how HTML handles it - the table will stretch to fit the width of its contents